# Firebase CLI save database:get result to variable in batch script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-tools

So, I'm making a website that involves a command in cmd to run several other powershell scripts on a server, and it needs input from  Firebase. So, I programmed the JavaScript to send details of a form to Firebase. I want to read information from the database in a batch script using Firebase CLI. So far, I've gotten it to work, printing out a JSON tree, but, how do I save the results to a variable in the batch script?
Below is some code that I've used to read from the database in the batch file.

```
CALL firebase database:get /orders/latest/
```

It prints out the following

> {"design":"IntroOne","email":"asdfasdf@gmail.com","huerotation":"0","name":"test"}

into the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvmd. I found it. https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/11/the-firebase-cli-now-with-database_82.html
I wan't looking hard enough. Sorry!